# How to display recently added data by date order in MySql?

Tags: mysql, sql, date, sql-order-by

I wish to sort my table with date order so that recently added data will be on the top of the table.

I have used query  for sorting as:

```
select date from register_table order by date desc.
```

Currently table display data as:

```
date

02.04.2019
05.04.2019
09.04.2019
10.04.2019
06.02.2019
23.01.2019
11.01.2019
```

I expect my table to display as:

```
date

10.04.2019
09.04.2019
05.04.2019
02.04.2019
06.02.2019
23.01.2019
11.01.2019
```

How to display data in date order?

Comment: Is it date type date? or varchar

Comment: @M.Hemant its varchar

Comment: Did you try Gordon Linoff 's answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fundamental problem is not storing the date as a `date`.  You should fix that.

For the query to work, use:

```
order by str_to_date(date, '%m.%d.%Y')
```

To fix the data, you can do:

```
update register_table
    set date = str_to_date(date, '%m.%d.%Y');

alter table register_table
    modify date date;
```

You can see how this works [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c2911018eda69003d3509a2cf4250aad).

Comment: I see now why mine wasn't working! So the `REPLACE` is not necessary. Thanks Gordon.

Comment: @binz . . . Is there a reason why you unaccepted this answer?  It is simpler than the alternative.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why your date is stored like that but here, give this a try:

```
SELECT date FROM date ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(REPLACE(date,'.','-'),'%d-%m-%Y') DESC;
```

If you want to see what exactly happen, run this query:

```
SELECT date,STR_TO_DATE(REPLACE(date,'.','-'),'%d-%m-%Y') FROM date;
```

In case you still don't quite understand, refer to [MySQL STR_TO_DATE function](https://www.w3schools.com/SQL/func_mysql_str_to_date.asp) and [MySQL REPLACE function](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-replace-function.php).